# Reduce space between image and text of button in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there any property for xamarin forms `Button` to reduce the gap between `Button` image  and `Button` text? I tried to use custom renderer, but I'm not sure which property should be set to reduce gap between image and text.

Adding more detail for clarity:
I have a `Button` that is of complete width of screen and a defined height. I have image and text property set for `Button`. While rendering, there is gap between image and text. I need to display text next to image without gap.

Any help would be really appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of button and text issue]

Comment: can you post a screen shot for better understanding..

Comment: Have your tried doing setting the `Button.ContentLayout` property? I believe that determines the image location and spacing. Maybe try: `<Button Image="plusicon.png" Text="Button" ContentLayout="Left,0"/>`

Comment: Trying to use ContentLayout gives following error:  No property, bindable property, or event found for 'ContentLayout'

Comment: I updated Xamarin forms and now app is identifying ContentLayout property, but there is no effect of spacing parameter,    <Button Text="Proceed" ContentLayout="Left,0" Clicked="OnProceedClicked"
                                 Image="refresh_blue.png"
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>

Comment: @hvaughan3 Do i  need to add any other property for ContentLayout?

Comment: I am not sure, I have never used that property myself. I wonder if it accepts negative values for the spacing? Something like `ContentLayout="Left,-5"`? If not you might just need to create your own button using a `StackLayout`, an `Image`, and a `Label` control.

Comment: Issue may be here with VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand". By setting VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" it seems invalidating the behavior of ContentLayout